# In react, whenever we are putting map loop in table it is calling item again and again?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

here I am setting data from redux store.

```
let data = useSelector((state) => state?.meterAlertsTableInput?.tabelData);
```

here doing map for item which is in row,

```
return (<TableBody>
   {data.map((item, i) => {
                 return <Row item={item} key={i} origin={props.origin} />;
   })}
 </TableBody>);
```

Comment: map method will iterate all the records, it's functionality of map method.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is calling item again and again?" ?

Comment: It is calling row function infinite time.